# Complement the exit status in if with -e set

Tags: bash

Is there a simple way to do something like:

```
if ! some_command; then
    some_commands;
fi
```

or

```
if [[ com1 && com2 ]]; then
    something;
fi
```

where it's the exit status of com1 and com2 that are used.

I realize that I can do things like get the exit status even with -e set by using || and check that, etc. Just wondering if there was something simpler that I am missing.

ADDENDUM: I also realize that I could do:

```
if some_command; then
else
    some_commands;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`!` can be used outside of an `if` statement; it's the general exit-status inverter, not part of the `if` syntax.

```
! some_command && { some_commands; }
```

and

```
some_command || { some_commands; }
```

are equivalent. You can also use

```
com1 && com2 && { some_commands; }
```

Answer (score 0):

for first: you can write something like: where `<command1/2>` is/are some command(s)/script(s) with/without parameter

```
$ <command1> 2>/dev/null || <command2> 2>/dev/null
```

for second: you can write something like:

```
$ ( <command1> && <command2> ) 2>/dev/null && <command3> 2>/dev/null
```

ex:

```
$ echo 1 2>/dev/null || echo 0 2>/dev/null
1

$ ech1o 1 2>/dev/null|| echo 0 2>/dev/null
0
```

AND

```
$ ( echo 1 && echo 2 ) 2>/dev/null && echo 3
1
2
3
```

The following won't print anything as echo 3 will never be executed (due to echo1 is not a valid command)

```
$ ( echo1 1 && echo 2 ) 2>/dev/null && echo 3
```